# импорт xml в бд на java

Tags: java, xml

Нужно произвести импорт записей из файла xml, все импортируется хорошо, но только первая запись, а нужно что бы все.
вот код импорта:

```
 Statement statement = null;
    Schema schema = null;
    try {
        statement = connection.createStatement();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Скопируйте файл в директорию, где находится программа" +
            "\n Введите имя файла xml соответствующего для импорта в таблицу Автомобили");
    String string = scanner.nextLine();
    String FILENAME = string + ".xml";

    try {

        final File xmlFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")
                + File.separator + FILENAME);
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(xmlFile);

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        try {
            SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
            schema = factory.newSchema(new File("xsd\\Auto.xsd"));
            Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
            validator.validate(new DOMSource(doc));


            System.out.println("Файл xml соответствует схемы данной таблицы");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Файл xml не соответствует  xsd схеме данной таблицы");
            return;
            //   e.printStackTrace();
        }

        NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Auto");


        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

            Node node = nodeList.item(i);


            if (Node.ELEMENT_NODE == node.getNodeType()) {
                Element element = (Element) node;
                String Model = element.getElementsByTagName("Model").item(0).getTextContent();
                String Data_vipuska = element.getElementsByTagName("Data_vipuska").item(0).getTextContent();
                String Color = element.getElementsByTagName("Color").item(0).getTextContent();
                String Probeg = element.getElementsByTagName("Probeg").item(0).getTextContent();
                String Price = element.getElementsByTagName("Price").item(0).getTextContent();

                statement.execute("INSERT INTO 'Auto'('Model','Data_vipuska','Color','Probeg','Price')" +
                        " VALUES ('" + Model + "','" + Data_vipuska + "','" +
                        Color + "','" + Probeg + "','" + Price + "'); ");
                System.out.println("Данные импортированы в таблицу");

            }
```

Вот пример xml:

```
 <Auto>
  <auto>
   <id_auto>1</id_auto>
   <Model>lalaz</Model>
   <Data_vipuska>2017</Data_vipuska>
   <Color>red</Color>
   <Probeg>100</Probeg>
   <Price>200</Price>
   </auto>
  <auto>
    <id_auto>1</id_auto>
    <Model>maz</Model>
    <Data_vipuska>2001</Data_vipuska>
    <Color>red</Color>
    <Probeg>100000</Probeg>
    <Price>1</Price>
  </auto>
</Auto>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как **xml** учитывает регистр, то эта строчка

```
NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Auto");
```

возвращает список из 1 элемента.

Вам надо использовать название узла в правильном регистре

```
NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("auto");
```

Вот этот код

```
NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("auto");
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
    Node node = nodeList.item(i);
    if (Node.ELEMENT_NODE == node.getNodeType()) {
        Element element = (Element) node;
        String Model = element.getElementsByTagName("Model").item(0).getTextContent();
        String Data_vipuska = element.getElementsByTagName("Data_vipuska").item(0).getTextContent();
        String Color = element.getElementsByTagName("Color").item(0).getTextContent();
        String Probeg = element.getElementsByTagName("Probeg").item(0).getTextContent();
        String Price = element.getElementsByTagName("Price").item(0).getTextContent();

        System.out.println("INSERT INTO 'Auto'('Model','Data_vipuska','Color','Probeg','Price')" +
                " VALUES ('" + Model + "','" + Data_vipuska + "','" +
                Color + "','" + Probeg + "','" + Price + "'); ");
    }
}
```

Выдает вот такой результат

```
INSERT INTO 'Auto'('Model','Data_vipuska','Color','Probeg','Price') VALUES ('lalaz','2017','red','100','200'); 
INSERT INTO 'Auto'('Model','Data_vipuska','Color','Probeg','Price') VALUES ('maz','2001','red','100000','1');
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. но приложение стало падать -                      
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException.                                                        В строке                                                                                           
    String Model = 
    element.getElementsByTagName("Model").item(0).getTextContent();

Comment: без  .item(0)  не удается реализовать метод getTextContent‌​()

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо! работает.

Comment: @Oleg, вам бы ещё познакомится с `PreparedStatement`...